# How do i format this function using strings in a database?

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

This is the function in a View package for a basic website. I have a folder called productImages and a function "getString" that takes string params from my database. In this database I have a column: image_name. I'm trying to make this function concat the getString with the image_name in the db to correctly append the actual image into a table. I've looked for similar questions but couldn't find anything I really understood. I appreciate any help.

```
sb.append(<img src="productImages"(results.getString("image_name"))+"/>");
```

Comment: I figured it out messing around. In case anyone has a similar problem, it's because the html renders as img src = productImageimage_name. It needs to be img src = "productImages/image_name". Here's the working code:                 'sb.append("<img src='productImages/" + results.getString("image_name") + "'/>");'

Comment: The problem here is that you're using an old discouraged technology called scriptlets and not following the MVC pattern.